# Why are the Google Maps controls & InfoWindow broken/skewed when using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile

Has anyone seen [Google Maps V3](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) not play nicely with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) Versions 1.1.0 RC1 or 1.0.1?

Using [jQuery 1.7.1](http://jquery.com).

The map controls & InfoWindow's are slightly skewed.

If one of the map divs changes from z-index:1 to :0 then it's fine.

I have no extra styling applied so I'm assuming it's being done by the Google Maps JavaScript.

Broken JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyaresu/zDVKn/7/

[image: Broken Google maps controls]

**EDIT**: Solution finally found! Yaaaaaay!

**SECOND EDIT** To correctly center the map. Remove the separate map div inside the content div.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDVKn/9/

Thanks. G.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#map_canvas img {
max-width: none;
}
```

Broken JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyaresu/zDVKn/7/

With CSS fix: http://jsfiddle.net/gyaresu/zDVKn/8/

**EDIT**: Final version with map div removed to enable correct centering.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDVKn/9/

Comment: The gift that keeps on giving :D

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs if you are using [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps) too. Fix with the following instead of accepted answer:

```
.angular-google-map img {
    max-width: inherit;
}
```